# Using classes in TCL using Simple Agent Pro

Tags: class, import, tcl

I am using this software called Simple Agent Pro, and it primarily uses TCL code. I was wondering anybody familiar with TCL or Sapro would be kind enough to tell me how to import the modules into the .tel file for Sapro.

When I try this:

```
package require tclOO.h
```

The program stops working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Simple Agent Pro at all, but if you're doing a “guerilla install” of TclOO then you need a few things:

- **Make sure you're using Tcl 8.5** (see what `package require Tcl` returns).

  - If you're using 8.4 (note: 8.4 EOLed this month), TclOO *will not work at all* (and it cannot be backported).
  - If you're using 8.6, it already provides the TclOO package and you shouldn't need to fuss around with all this.
- Do a **build of TclOO** and install it to a location you prefer.

  - This *will* require Tcl's internal source files; TclOO explicitly pokes its nose into places where most code shouldn't.
  - You probably don't need to have a custom build of 8.5; just the `configure`d sources somewhere will do. (You might need to hack the configure scripts a little bit.)
- **Add the location** that you installed TclOO to to the search path inside your Tcl 8.5 program.

  ```
  lappend auto_path /the_dir/you_put/it_in
  ```

  If you're using Windows, it's probably easiest to use forward slashes for this path anyway (this is a directory name that is always highly protected before it hits the OS, so that's OK).
- Now you should be able to **require/use the package**.

  ```
  package require TclOO

  oo::class create Foo {
      # etc.
  }
  ```

  Note that the case and exactly how you write it matters. The version you get ought to be at least 1.0 (earlier versions were for development only) which corresponds exactly with the API as supported in Tcl 8.6 (modulo a few things that require 8.6 for other reasons, such as being able to `yield` inside a method which only works in 8.6 because that's where `yield` was first defined).

Comment: The lappend did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean

```
package require TclOO
```

Case and other stuff is important there.

Next time you should also include the stack trace. If the program stops working, it should display that either as dialog or on stdout.

Comment: I did try that..The problem is it's inside a .tel file and proper debugging is not possible. The best i can is try print statements and this is the point that doesn't work

Comment: Ok, then try this to debug: `proc dbgPkg {cmd code result step} {if {[lindex $cmd 1]=="require"} {puts "\[$cmd\] returned \"$result\" with return code $code"}}; trace add execution package leave dbgPkg` - trace is a very powerful tool for debugging.